# Python importing csv files within subfolders

Tags: python, jupyter, glob

Is there a way of importing all the files within folder1? Each csv file is contained within a subfolder. Below is the file structure.

C:/downloads/folder1 > **tree /F**

```
C:.
│   tree
│
├───2020-06
│       test1.csv
│
├───2020-07
│       test2.csv
│
├───2020-08
│       test3.csv
│
├───2020-09
│       test4.csv
```

I'm aware of glob, below, to take all files within a folder. However can this be used for subfolders?

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

# Get a list of all the csv files
csv_files = glob.____('*.csv')

# List comprehension that loads of all the files
dfs = [pd.read_csv(____) for ____ in ____]

# List comprehension that looks at the shape of all DataFrames
print(____)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.walk` to find all sub_folder and get the required files

here's a code sample

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = '<Insert Path>'
file_extension = '.csv'
csv_file_list = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith(file_extension):
            file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
            csv_file_list.append(file_path)

dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_file_list]
```

Comment: Is there a way of then importing the list of files into seperate dataframes?

Comment: The list comprehension method you used in your sample would work just file.

Comment: I have added the list comprehension in the answer

Answer (score 3):

Use the `recursive` keyword argument of the [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) method:

```
glob.glob('**\\*.csv', recursive=True)
```

Comment: Is there a way of importing the list of file paths into a dataframe?

Comment: @IOIOIOIOIOIOI You mean `[pandas.read_csv(file) for file in glob('**\\*.csv', recursive=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

I found this on [Kite's](https://www.kite.com/python/answers/how-to-search-for-specific-files-in-subdirectories-in-python) website, check it out

```
path = "./directory/src_folder"

text_files = glob.glob(path + "/**/*.txt", recursive = True)

print(text_files)
OUTPUT
['./directory/src_folder/src_file.txt', './directory/src_folder/subdirectory/subdirectory_file.txt']
```